# Creating date/time ranges with Oracle TIMESTAMP WITH TIMEZONE datatype

Tags: sql, database, oracle

How does one create date/time ranges for `TIMESTAMP WITH TIMEZONE` timestamps with a range precision down to the level of seconds?

Here is my sample query, however I can only create ranges down to the day level:

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME, MY_TIMESTAMP
FROM TABLE_NAME
WHERE (MY_TIMESTAMP BETWEEN SYSDATE - INTERVAL '1' DAY 
  AND SYSDATE - INTERVAL '0' DAY)
ORDER BY MY_TIMESTAMP
```

Here is the `TIMESTAMP` format used by the database:

```
30-AUG-10 04.20.00.109000 PM -07:00
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the 'SECOND' qualifier on your INTERVAL, as in:

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME, MY_TIMESTAMP 
  FROM TABLE_NAME 
  WHERE MY_TIMESTAMP >= SYSDATE - INTERVAL '3600' SECOND
  ORDER BY MY_TIMESTAMP
```

The above should give you all rows with a timestamp within the last hour.

You may need to use SYSTIMESTAMP instead of SYSDATE to get around the issues raised by TIMESTAMP WITH TIMEZONE.

Share and enjoy.